# android studio autofocus qr scanner

Tags: java, android

I want to autofocus ore have a better quality cam can somebody help me with that? I want my qr scanner to autofocus and i want to switch the cam to front and the back.
this is my code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SurfaceView cameraPreview;
    TextView txtResult;
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    ImageButton cameraSwitch;
    final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
                        cameraPreview.findFocus();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
           }
           break;
       }

    }

    //QR-code scanner
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cameraPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        cameraSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraSwitch);

        txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource
                .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(500, 500)
                .build();

        cameraSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

            }
        });
```

any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

`QrCodeReaderView` library will help you to do that. This library uses **ZXING Library**

You can get the library here: https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView

You can set auto focus and you can change camera also.

```
qrCodeReaderView = (QRCodeReaderView) findViewById(R.id.qrdecoderview);
        qrCodeReaderView.setOnQRCodeReadListener(this);

          // Use this function to enable/disable decoding
        qrCodeReaderView.setQRDecodingEnabled(true);

        // Use this function to change the autofocus interval (default is 5 secs)
        qrCodeReaderView.setAutofocusInterval(2000L);

        // Use this function to enable/disable Torch
        qrCodeReaderView.setTorchEnabled(true);

        // Use this function to set front camera preview
        qrCodeReaderView.setFrontCamera();

        // Use this function to set back camera preview
        qrCodeReaderView.setBackCamera();
```

Hope it helps:)